# how to get delegate from ScheduledFuture task

Tags: java, spring

ClassA schedules TaskA

ClassB (child class of ClassA) schedules TaskB and TaskC

Im trying to unit test the structure; when breakpointing I see the information i need but how can I retrieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the source code of `org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable` [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/support/DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java).

**Use Reflection**

As you can see, `delegate` is declared in `private` scope without a getter. So the only way to access it is using `reflection`. However, if it is defined as private and without a getter, you need to have a good reason to have a need to access it.